# Using a VB.Net variable in an outlook HTML body

Tags: html, vb.net, outlook

I am using the following code that should write a HTML body for an outlook email, but where I am using a variable, the HTML uses the variable tag instead of the value. How do I get it to use the value instead of thinking it's part of the HTML?

**Code**

```
<p class="MsoNormal"><span style='color:#1F497D'> NameOfPerson has added AmountOfNewEntries to the database</span></p>
```

`NameOfPerson` and `AmountOfNewEntries` should display their values and not the actual text.

I've tried using `<#%NameOfPerson#%>` but it errors saying that the tag needs to be closed, assuming it is a HMTL tag.

Thanks

Comment: String.Format("<p class=""MsoNormal""><span style='color:#1F497D'> {0} has added {1} to the database</span></p>",NameOfPerson,AmountOfNewEntries)

Comment: I get the error: `Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'System.Xml.Linq.XElement'.` when trying to use this

Comment: you wanted xml literals? well  check this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384964.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the variables refer to `XElement` objects, and you need to pass the value of those elements as strings into HTML to form part of the body of the email, maybe you could use `String.Format` and the `Value` property of `XElement` as below?

`String.Format("<p class=""MsoNormal""><span style='color:#1F497D'> {0} has added {1} to the database</span></p>", NameOfPerson.Value, AmountOfNewEntries.Value)`